# TypeError: _notification.default.localNotification is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am kinda new in react native and I am trying to implement local push notification in my app and when I try to use push notifications I have this error:
`TypeError: _notification.default.localNotification is not a function. (In '_notification.default.localNotification()', '_notification.default.localNotification' is undefined)`.
I tried variety options but still cant figure out what is wrong.

Here is my configuration class for react-native-push-notifications:

```
export default class NotificationService {
  constructor(onNotification) {
    this.configure(onNotification);
    this.lastId = 0;
  }

  configure(onNotification) {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: onNotification,

      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },

      popInitialNotification: true,
    });
  }

  localNotification() {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotification.createChannel(
      {
        channelId: "custom-channel-id", // (required)
      },
    );
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: "custom-channel-id",
      title: "Local Notification", 
      message: "My Notification Message", 
      playSound: false, 
      soundName: 'default', 
      actions: '["Yes", "No"]'
    });
  }

  scheduleNotification() {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      date: new Date(Date.now() + (30 * 1000)), //30 seconds
      title: "Scheduled Notification", 
      message: "My Notification Message",
      playSound: true, 
      soundName: 'default', 
    });
  }

  checkPermission(cbk) {
    return PushNotification.checkPermissions(cbk);
  }

  cancelNotif() {
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: ''+this.lastId});
  }

  cancelAll() {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
  }
}
```

and my class where I want to trigger notification:

```
import { localNotification } from '../../service/notification.service'


notif() {
    localNotification();
}


.
.
.
.

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.notif}>
  <LinearGradient
    style={theme.ButtonSettings}
    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
    colors={[theme.GRADIENT_BLUE_1, theme.GRADIENT_BLUE_2]}>
    <MyText style={theme.buttonSettingsText}>zapisz</MyText>
   </LinearGradient>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

I sitting on this a lot of hours, I dont know that is problem with react-native-push-notification configuration or maybe just some stupid mistake with importing or smh.

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating your Notification service anywhere.

You could try:

`import { NotificationService } from '../../service/notification.service'` (by the way this is a weird looking import path, is your file actually `.service`?) assuming `notification.service` is the name of the file in which you declared `NotificationService`

then somewhere in the component where you want to call the method, for example it's `constructor` method or `componentDidMount` method you would declare an instance of the `NotificationService`, passing it an `onNotification` method:

`const myNotificationService = new NotificationService(onNotification)`

and then in your `notif` method, you can call the `localNotification` method as such:

`notif() {myNotificationService.localNotification()}`

Alternatively, inside your `ClassNotification` file, instead of exporting `ClassNotification`, you could export an instance of it that would be used throughout the rest of your code (singleton pattern)

Comment: I did what u told me and now I have ```ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onNotification``` according to this line: ```const myNotificationService = new NotificationService(onNotification)```

Comment: You would have to define `onNotification` somehwere else in your code. From your NotificationService class, it looks like this is a method you have to pass to the class constructor.